# How to solve this Firebase cloud function Error: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am following a [tutorial](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/the-ultimate-beginners-guide-to-firebase/#5-Cloud-Functions)  where I am adding some Firebase Cloud Functions to my project (step 5). I have successfully deployed my cloud function to firebase but nothing happens when I add a new product manually in the Firebase Database console. I discovered that the Firebase cloud function is triggered but it is getting an error: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined**"

What am I doing wrong?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


    exports.sendMessage = functions.firestore
        .document('products/{productId}')
        .onCreate(event => {

        const docId = event.params.productId; // <-- error here

        const name = event.data.data().name;
        const productRef = admin.firestore().collection('products').doc(docId)
        return productRef.update({ message: `Nice ${name}! - Love Cloud Functions`})

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So thanks to Dough Stevensson's answer notifying me that the syntax was old I have now a solution:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var db = admin.firestore();

exports.sendMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('products/{productId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

       const docId = context.params.productId;

       const productRef = db.collection('products').doc(docId)
       return productRef.update({ message: `Nice ${name}!`})
    });
```

Comment: You forgot to define name here. Thank you for seeking the proper way to do this tough!

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial must be out of date.  Some things have changed in the Functions SDK when it released version 1.0.  You can read about those changes [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff).

Database triggers are now passed two parameters instead of one.  The new context parameter contains the value of wildcards in the reference path:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('products/{productId}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    const docId = context.params.productId;
```

If you want to continue with that tutorial, you'll have to manually convert all of its old stuff to new stuff.